# groupdatamodel not taking in given order

Tags: database, listview, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

The problem i am facing is that the data listed in list view is in ascending order in BB10. I have read from blackberry site that group datamodel will display data either in desc or asc order.I really want them to be displayed in list view in the order they are in database.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an `id` field in your database, you could use it to sort your items.
But I guess you shouldn't be using a [`GroupDataModel`](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__groupdatamodel.html) if you don't want to group your data (if you don't sort it, how can you group?). What you need is probably an [`ArrayDataModel`](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__arraydatamodel.html), or your own [`DataModel`](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__datamodel.html) subclass.